# Inheriting from BaseException vs Exception

Tags: python-3.x

I know what is difference between `Exception` and `BaseException` in `Python`. I wonder what is a good practice and more *pythonic*:
Should my exceptions inherit from `BaseException` or `Exception`?

Comment: There is a good video explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrVfY9SuO64&ab_channel=mCoding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, all user-defined exceptions should inherit from `Exception`. This is [recommended in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception):

> exception `Exception`
>
> All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class. **All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.**

This is also [recommend by and motivated in PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Derive exceptions from `Exception` rather than `BaseException`. Direct inheritance from `BaseException` is reserved for exceptions where catching them is almost always the wrong thing to do.

---

In general, exceptions deriving from `Exception` are intended to be handled by regular code. In contrast, exceptions deriving directly from `BaseException` are associated with special situations; handling them like normal exceptions can lead to unexpected behaviour. This is why an idiomatic "catch all" handler only handles `Exception`:

```
def retry(func):
    while True:
        try:
            return func()
        except Exception as err:
            print(f"retrying after {type(err)}: {err}")
```

Builtin exceptions inheriting directly from `BaseException` currently are `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, and `GeneratorExit` which are associated with shutdown of the program, thread or generator/coroutine. Incorrectly handling them will prevent a graceful shutdown.

Note that while the default should be to inherit from `Exception`, it is fine to inherit from `BaseException` if there is a good reason to do so. For example, [`asyncio.CancelledError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) also inherits from `BaseException` since it represents shutdown of `asyncio`'s thread equivalent, the Task.