# Multiple Inheritance: Exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, inheritance

I am designing some custom exceptions in my python project. Suppose they are called `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Oat`. They are all exception classes that stand independently as their own Python files.

Foo inherits from `BaseException`:

```py
class Foo(BaseException):
    pass
```

I am getting a Python exception indicating that I *must* inherit from `BaseException` in order to use the `raise` keyword with this object (i.e. raise the exception).

I get this Python exception in `bar.py` which is an exception that inherits from `foo.py`. Because `bar.py` *does not* directly inherit from `BaseException`, is it incorrectly designed?

Do I need every Python exception to *directly* inherit from `BaseException`? Or is there a way to implement multiple inheritance?

```
Foo <--- Bar <--- Oat [Inheritance where Apple  <--(is-a)-- Fruit]
```

For further clarification although someone has detailed in the comments...

```py
def Foo(BaseException):
    pass
```

```py
def Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

```py
def Oat(Bar):
    pass
```

The issue was that when I call `raise Bar` my program fails saying Bar cannot be called as it needs to be derived from BaseException.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I cannot reproduce this from your desription alone.

Comment: If you have `class Foo(BaseException):` and `class Bar(Foo):` and `class Oat(Bar):`, then `raise Oat` works just fine.  I just did it.  If these are in different files, make sure you didn't try to derive from the module.  That is, do `class Bar(foo.Foo)`, not `class Bar(foo)`.

Comment: "They are all exception classes that stand independently as their own Python files."  note, classes are not files, files correspond to *modules*.\

Comment: Note, what you describe here **is not multiple inheritance**

Comment: ["It is not meant to be directly inherited by user-defined classes (for that, use Exception)."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) ("It" referring to `BaseException`.)

Comment: Class definitions look like `class Foo` rather than `def Foo`.  What `def Foo` does is define a function (with a parameter named `BaseException`).  So when you then try to `raise Foo`, you get the error you see, because `Foo` is a function, not an instance of (a subclass of) `BaseException`.

Answer (score 1):

You must inherit from `BaseException`, but it doesn't have to be your direct ancestor. It just needs to be somewhere up the chain.

That's completely unremarkable. In fact, almost all exceptions in the standard library are *not* direct ancestors of `Exception`:

[image]

Actually, most exceptions should derive from `Exception`, *not* `BaseException`. See [Inheriting from BaseException vs Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745841/inheriting-from-baseexception-vs-exception)

So this is perfectly reasonable:

#### `foo.py`

```py
class Foo(Exception):
    pass
```

#### `bar.py`

```py
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

#### `oat.py`

```py
class Oat(Bar):
    pass
```

Comment: While this is true, this doesn't explain why the OP is seeing an error. It is probably best to wait for them to post a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't get the impression that OP was getting an error. I thought the core of the question (which I am answering) is "is it incorrectly designed?"

Comment: "I am getting a Python exception indicating that I must inherit from BaseException in order to use the raise keyword with this object (i.e. raise the exception)." So, try something like `class X: pass` then `raise X`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga They've gone past that and said that they've already inherited from `BaseException`, at least for `Foo`. They're then wondering if it's appropriate for the other classes to inherit from `Foo` and not (directly) from `BaseException`.

Comment: Look at the OP's edit. It's quite clear they are getting the error. And the reason is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explicitly states twice that user-defined exceptions should inherit from `Exception`, not `BaseException`.

> *exception* **BaseException**
>
> The base class for all built-in exceptions. It is not meant to be directly inherited by user-defined classes (for that, use `Exception`)....

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException)

and

> *exception* **Exception**
>
> All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception)

The exception refers to the attempt to raise a value that is *not* ultimately derived from `BaseException`:

```
>>> raise "Foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```